# Jaxb marshaller always writes xsi:nil (even when @XmlElement(required=false, nillable=true))

Tags: jaxb, marshalling, xml-nil

I have a java property annotated with `@XmlElement(required=false, nillable=true)`. When the object is marshalled to xml, it is always outputted with the `xsi:nil="true"` attribute.

Is there a jaxbcontext/marshaller option to direct the marshaller not to write the element, rather than write it with `xsi:nil`?

I've looked for answers to this and also had a look at the code, afaics, it will always write `xsi:nil` if `nillable = true`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the property is annotated with `@XmlElement(required=false, nillable=true)` and the value is null it will be written out with `xsi:nil="true"`.

If you annotate it with just `@XmlElement` you will get the behaviour you are looking for.

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

**Example**

Given the following class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlElement(nillable=true, required=true)
    private String elementNillableRequired;

    @XmlElement(nillable=true)
    private String elementNillbable;

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    private String elementRequired;

    @XmlElement
    private String element;

}
```

And this demo code:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Root root = new Root();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

The result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <elementNillableRequired xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <elementNillbable xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was seeing in the code as well. I didn't want to change the annotations since it was generated code, and also because it is an accurate reflection of the xml schema (which defined the elements as minoccurs='0' and nillable='true').

Comment: FWIW, it appears that `@XmlElement(required=false)` also produces the desired behavior.

Comment: Hrmmm ... I know this is old but, the elementRequired being null should actually throw an error (right?) ... because its null yet required. In my case, we are using cxf / SOAP.

Comment: I try to extend your example where elementNillableRequired element has atribute and then it doesnt work. It create invalid element. I just set atribute and let value be null: <elementNillableRequired status="N" /> (nillable is missing)

Comment: @hudi - I will take a look at the corresponding question you posted:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28537873/jaxb-create-invalid-nillable-element-when-generate-xml-against-xsd

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan did you already check my question ? I would be very grateful for your help