# Ignoring null values when marshaling an object to JSON with RESTeasy and Jettison

Tags: json, rest, resteasy, jettison

When RESTeasy marshals a POJO into XML, it will skip null values by default: See [Jaxb marshaller always writes xsi:nil (even when @XmlElement(required=false, nillable=true))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897785/jaxb-marshaller-always-writes-xsinil-even-when-xmlelementrequired-false-nil#5898163).

However, when marshaling to JSON, null properties are included. Is there any way to force the JSON output to match the XML output?

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that null values are not included in the JSON, the following annotation can be applied on the getter or public variable declaration:
    @JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL)