# How to prevent generation of xml 'nil' elements in soap webservice client?

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, cxf, jax-ws

I have an autogenerated soap webservice client (using `cxf`), and some elements are marked to be optional.

If I do not set these elements, the XML request send to the webservice has lot's of elements as follows:

```
<PayText xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
<Name xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

These are generated if the `wsdl` contains:

```
minOccurs="0" nillable="true"
```

How can I prevent the generation of these `nil` elements?
Probably the webservice itself does not need this information, as when I use `soapUI` and the send the pure xml requests stripping out the nil elements, the request still works.

My binding file:

```
<jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false" />
```

So, how can I prevent them being generated during send?

Comment: Possible duplicate (at least a relevant question with answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897785/jaxb-marshaller-always-writes-xsinil-even-when-xmlelementrequired-false-nil

Comment: Not really. I have neither control of the `wsdl` (I'm just the client), nor on the autogenerated classes (as they must be regenerated every time a wsdl update takes place).

Comment: Well, in that case you're probably out of luck because of the 'nillable=true' which is present in the WSDL.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an element is `minOccurs="0"` and `nillable="true"` then the generated property type will be a `JAXBElement`, something like `JAXBElement<String>`. When that property is `null` it will be excluded from the marshalled XML (null corresponds to `minOccurs="0"`).  To get `xsi:nil="true"` you need to have an instance of `JAXBElement` with `nil` set to `true`.

Comment: So it is due to my `<jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false" />`? I want to prevent working with `JAXBElement`, but have the property directly, that's why I work with `generateElementProperty = false`. It it then impossible to remove the nil elements from the marshalled xml, as they are generated as consequence of the property??

Comment: This is one of the cases where `JAXBElement` is useful.  Without it the property will be annotated with `@XmlElement(nillable=true)` will cause the behaviour you are seeing.  Why don't you want to use `JAXBElement`?

Comment: I'm preventing the use of jaxbelement to have one less element property to walk when accessing the autogenerated element properties. Could it be generally said if JAXBElement should be used in a project or not?

Comment: And also, I just can create the classes themself, not having to go through the way `new ObjectFactory().createTheElement("test");`.